# Create A New Row and Select A Cell

Tags: excel, vba, rows, offset

I am trying to give users the ability to add rows to a form, however I need them to do it programmatically so that the new row contains a checkbox with a macro already assigned to it.

My solution has been to insert a row with an InputBox, which works great.

```
Dim rowloc As String

rowloc = InputBox("Location to Insert Row", "What row do you want to insert 
the new row ABOVE?")

Rows(rowloc).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

But I am having a heck of a time going to column B in that *new* row and inserting the checkbox. I don't have issues with making a new button in VBA, it's just getting to the other cell that's the issue.

```
Rows(rowloc).Offset(0, 1).Select
```

doesn't work either. Any helpful hints or solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thw `Rows(rowloc)` is a Range that includes all the cells in the row `rowloc`. If you need to identify a cell in this Range (in this row) then, for example,

```
Rows(rowloc).Cells(2).Select ' in column 2 ("B")
```

or, equivalently,

```
Rows(rowloc).Parent.Cells(rowloc,2).Select ' in column 2 ("B")
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(rowloc,2).Select ' in column 2 ("B")
     ' might not be the same worksheet though, depending on your setup
```

etc.